# News Web Part not showing image thumbnails in Sharepoint Server 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, news-webpart

I am creating the news post on Sharepoint communication site, and adding the image in the content, leaving the banner as default. However, the News web part is not showing the image in the thumbnail. It was working few days earlier. Can anyone guide me how to troubleshoot this issue. All I am doing is clicking New --> News Post --> Adding title, image in the content and text. The text appears but not the image.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: What is the source of the selected image ?

Comment: Can you show me the browser console output ?

Comment: The source of the image is the image library of the same sharepoint site. I will update the browser console output soon